# Why are this two divs one next to each other, does someone know why this footer is not working?

Tags: html, css, deployment, footer

My intention is to display the logo and underneath of it, 3 buttons with all of the social media links. However, I don't know why, it makes my 2 divs display inline instead of flex or block. Does somebody know why is this not working?

```css
.foot {
  background-color: #152238;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  border-top: solid 2px #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.foot h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Kdam Thmor Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kdam+Thmor+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<footer>
    <div class="foot">
      <div>
        <h2>Shop</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info gmail"><i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i> Gmail</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info insta"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info tiktok"><i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i> TikTok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

I've tried changing the display method, using bootstrap rows and even `<br>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a `flex`-box will try to squeeze its items into a single `row`. To change this, you need `flex-direction: column`:

```css
.foot {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.foot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #152238;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  border-top: solid 2px #ffffff;
}

.foot h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Kdam Thmor Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kdam+Thmor+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<footer>
    <div class="foot">
      <div>
        <h2>Shop</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info gmail"><i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i> Gmail</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info insta"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info tiktok"><i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i> TikTok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use flex, you need to specify the direction of the items. Flex comes with different directions:

> row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;

Since you want to display them on top of each other, just add this to your foot class:

```
flex-direction: column;
```